# Ejabberd contact list grouping and show contact list if its connected with parent entity

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, one-to-one, chatroom

System has 2 type of Entities,

1. EntityType1
2. EntityType2

Now system has
for ex.

**2 EntityType1**

1. EntityType-1.1 - 5 Users   - Mark wood
2. EntityType-1.2 - 5 Users   - Mark wood

&

**2 EntityType2**

1. EntityType2.1 - 3 Users
2. EntityType2.2 - 3 Users

Now EntityType1 can connect with EntityType2. So Once the EntityType-1.1 is connected with EntityType2.1, EntityType-1.1 users can chat with its 5 users + EntityType2.1 entitys 3 users. Now EntityType-1.1 sends connection request to EntityType2.2 and got connected. So now EntityType-1.1 can chat with EntityType-1.1 employyes, EntityType2.1 users & EntityType2.2 users.

Now, Mark wood has access of 2 employers. EntityType-1.1 & EntityType-1.2.
But it should show contact list entity wise. So When Mark is working under EntityType-1.1 it should show chat users of EntityType-1.1, EntityType2.1 & EntityType2.2.
And when mark is working for EntityType-1.2 it should show chat users of EntityType-1.2 only.

Can somebody please guide me with the reference if known